# ¿Error en phpMyAdmin?¿Como lo arreglo?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

lo que pasa es que cuando guardo un dato mediante mi formulario de Python con libreria tkinter, no se visualiza en el phpMyAdmin,
(Si ingresa el dato pero no se visualiza), aparece filas mas no el dato.

```
#### Codigo formulario simple###

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql
from pymysql import connect
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import cursor

ven=Tk()
ven.title("G")
ven.geometry("700x400")
ven.resizable(False,False)

miNombre=StringVar()
no=miNombre.get()

def guardar():
    try:
        con=pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",password='',db='canguro')
        cur=con.cursor()
        re="INSERT INTO nombre (nom)VALUES('{0}')".format(no)
        cur.execute(re)
        con.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Bien Hecho")
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error")

Label (ven,text="Nombre").place(x=30, y=30)
Entry(ven,textvariable=miNombre).place(x=120, y=30)
Button(ven, text="Guardar Registro",command=guardar).place(x=550, y=35, width=140)

ven.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kchNb.jpg)

Comment: La variable `no` la tienes fuera de la función `guardar()`, con lo que siempre tendrá el mismo valor inicial (o sea, estará vacío). Si quieres guardar el contenido del `miNombre`, obtén su valor justo antes de hacer el _insert_.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que tienes que hacer una llamada a la función directamente, algo así:

```
Button(ven, text="Guardar Registro",command=guardar()).place(x=550, y=35, width=140)
```